# Help with images

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, list-view, design

Why when I have uploaded onto SharePoint - it looks great and when I share out to my colleagues the pictures are missing and they can't view?

Please help.

Comment: Are you sharing/granting permissions on individual files with your colleagues?

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can check:

1. The files/pictures you uploaded are **not checked out** --> Check-in & publish properly
2. Your colleagues have necessary permissions to view newly uploaded pictures.
3. Make sure you don't have Item-level Permissions on individual pictures.

Comment: Thank you I did look around on the settings and allowed access not full as some colleagues were just visitors - this might have solved the problem but I will try the other suggestions too -

Comment: Great, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.